# Mysql REGEXP return results and matched values

Tags: mysql, regex, match

I need to do a search in mysql:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM table 
 WHERE data REGEXP 'firstValue|secondValue|thirdValue'
```

What i need is to retrieve the the rows matching for example firstValue, and return these rows and the matched term in the result of the query, for example:

```
id     -     data                        - matched_term
 1     -  blabla firstValue              -  firstValue
 2     -  blabla secondValue blabla      -  secondValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (case when data regexp 'firstvalue' then 'firstValue'
             when data regexp 'secondValue' then 'secondValue'
             when data regexp 'thirdValue' then 'thirdValue'
        end) as which
FROM table t
WHERE data REGEXP 'firstValue|secondValue|thirdValue';
```

If you are doing just constant comparisons (meaning that `data` exactly matches exactly one of the values), then I would suggest different functions:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (case when data = 'firstvalue' then 'firstValue'
             when data = 'secondValue' then 'secondValue'
             when data = 'thirdValue' then 'thirdValue'
        end) as which
FROM table t
WHERE data in (firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue')
```

Comment: it could serve if the matches where a few, but they could be thousands, i mean "first|second|third|fourth|...thousand"